# Find tag by id using acts_as_taggable_on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm using Ruby on rails 2.3.8 and acts_as_taggable_on plugin. This plugin generates three tables: tags(which has the id and name of each tag) and taggings(relates tag_ids which the items that are tagged).

Now, I'd like to get all the items tagged with a certain tag_id. So, I go to my Announcement model(the announcements are the tagged items) and I'd like to write something like this:

```
def find_by_category(tag_id)
  Announcement.tagged_with(tag_id) #this doesn't exist.
end
```

But the only method I found actually was this:

```
Announcement.tagged_with(tag_NAME) #this works, but I don't want to find by a name.
```

Does anybody know a method to accomplish this, or at least, how to modify the plugin's code to do this?

Answer (score 8):

```
tag = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.find(tag_id)  
Announcement.tagged_with(tag)
```

A year later, I hope this is helpful for someone!

Answer (score 0):

acts_as_taggable has a method

```
Model.find_tagged_with @tag_name
```

That works for me in a couple of projects.

[Method docs](http://taggable.rubyforge.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Acts/Taggable/SingletonMethods.src/M000001.html)

Comment: He said he wants to find by id, not name.